# Finding results with mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, discord, discord.js

I have a db full of skills and I'm trying to make an info cmd where if you type the skill name you will get some info on it. Some skills are 2-3 arguments. For example "Animal Call". I want to be able to find my skill in mongodb by typing both `!info animal call` and for example something short like `!info ani call`

The problem about this is that if i try to find it with `!info ani call` it wont show up as a result.

Here's my code:

```
let skill = args.slice(0).join(" ");

const skillDB = await Skill.find({})

for (let i = 0; i < skillDB.length; i++) {
 if (skillDB[i].skillName.toLowerCase().includes(`${skill.toLowerCase()}`)) {
  const embed = new MessageEmbed()
  .setDescription(`\`${skillDB[i].skillIcon}\` ${skillDB[i].skillName}`)
  .setImage(skillDB[i].skillImg)
  return message.channel.send(embed)
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will need to use some kind of regex here. Instead of `join`ing the arguments by a space, you could join them by `.*` and use that as a regex.

`.*` matches any characters, so when you join `['ani', 'call']`, it will become a string like `'ani.*call'`. As a regex pattern, `/ani.*call/` matches any string that contains both `ani` and `call` (in this order).

```js
const args = ['ani', 'call']
const regex = new RegExp(args.join('.*'), 'i')

console.log(`Words matching ${regex}:`)
console.log('animal', regex.test('animal'))
console.log('animal call', regex.test('animal call'))
console.log('anime caller', regex.test('anime caller'))
console.log('anicall', regex.test('anicall'))
console.log('animal cruelty', regex.test('animal cruelty'))
console.log('anemia caribou', regex.test('anemia caribou'))
```

If you don't want to match words without any additional characters between them, you can join the words with `.+`. Using the `+` sign requires at least one extra character between the two strings; this way it won't match `anicall`:

```js
const args = ['ani', 'call']
const regex = new RegExp(args.join('.+'), 'i')

console.log(`Words matching ${regex}:`)
console.log('animal', regex.test('animal'))
console.log('animal call', regex.test('animal call'))
console.log('anime caller', regex.test('anime caller'))
console.log('anicall', regex.test('anicall'))
console.log('animal cruelty', regex.test('animal cruelty'))
console.log('anemia caribou', regex.test('anemia caribou'))
```

You could also use `[a-z\s]+` to only accept characters in the range a-z and whitespace:

```js
const args = ['ani', 'call']
const regex = new RegExp(args.join('[a-z\\s]+'), 'i')

console.log(`Words matching ${regex}:`)
console.log('animal', regex.test('animal'))
console.log('animal call', regex.test('animal call'))
console.log('anime caller', regex.test('anime caller'))
console.log('anicall', regex.test('anicall'))
console.log('animal cruelty', regex.test('animal cruelty'))
console.log('anemia caribou', regex.test('anemia caribou'))
```

With your current code, you could use the [`.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) method instead of `.includes()`. It searches for a match between a regex and a specified string.

You could also use a [`for ... of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop instead of the for loop to make it more readable:

```js
const regex = new RegExp(args.join('[a-z\\s]+'), 'i');
const skills = await Skill.find({});
const embed = new MessageEmbed();

for (let skill of skills) {
  if (regex.test(skill.skillName)) {
    embed
      .setDescription(`\`${skill.skillIcon}\` ${skill.skillName}`)
      .setImage(skill.skillImg);

    return message.channel.send(embed);
  }
}
```

I'm not sure why you're fetching every skill from the database though. You could also use [`find()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) or [`findOne()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne) with the regex above to only fetch the data you need:

```js
const regex = new RegExp(args.join('[a-z\\s]+'), 'i');
// findOne returns a single object or null if not found
const skill = await Skill.findOne({
  skillName: { $regex: regex },
});

if (!skill) {
  return message.channel.send(
    `Oops, I couldn't find any skill in the database for \`${args.join(' ')}\``,
  );
}

const embed = new MessageEmbed()
  .setDescription(`\`${skill.skillIcon}\` ${skill.skillName}`)
  .setImage(skill.skillImg);

return message.channel.send(embed);
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, this worked but what if I want to search by + too? For example a skill called "De+S". That regex doesn't let me search that.

Comment: You can add the `+` sign to your character class: `args.join('[a-z\\s+]+'), 'i')`